# UIBarButtonItem: how to skin the highlighted state

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

I have an image for a UIBarButtonItem but I do not want the highlighted state to show. Right now my image gets greyed out when the button is pressed. I tried to set the same image for the highlighted state but that didn't do anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this my friend:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIButton/adjustsImageWhenHighlighted

setting the buttons

```
adjustImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
```

should do the trick.

Hope it helps. Cheers

**UPDATE:**

```
// Initialize the UIButton
UIButton *customButton= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

//normal_button.png and selected_button.png need to be created by you
[customButton setBackgroundImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"normal_button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[customButton setBackgroundImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"normal_button.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: customButton];
```

Another way to do this.

Comment: Thanks but that's only for the UIBUtton class, not the UIBarButtonItem

Comment: Glad to help. Sorry I was not more specific the first time around. Happy coding.

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work. My custom button image would not be displayed.

Comment: If you show some of your code and screenshots in the question, I could probably better assist you.